# Trying to find examples of --strip-trailing-slashes

Tags: symlink, mv

I find the `--strip-trailing-slashes` option of the `mv` command confusing.

According to the official GNU manual, this option is "useful when a source argument may have a trailing slash and specify a symbolic link to a directory."
So I try the following:

```
$ mkdir a
$ ln -s a b 
$ mv --strip-trailing-slashes b/ c
```

and I get `mv: cannot move 'b' to 'c': Not a directory`, while I expect `b` to be renamed as `c`.

Do I misunderstand this option? Are there any examples of how to use this option?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with coreutils 8.28. The link gets renamed and I don't get any errors.

Comment: With `b` as a symlink, as per the question, I can reproduce with GNU coreutils 8.30.

Comment: @muru - Are you sure you still get no errors? Any alias that set the mv to a different behaviour? I am with the OP and John1024 getting the same error.

Comment: @midnite with coreutils 8.28 specifically? Just tried on an Ubuntu 18.04 container, and yes: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BzDbWJfDW3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `mv` may become confusing sometimes.

There are two alternatives to a `mv` command with **two** arguments:

```
mv one two
```

One, and the default, is to move the **file** `one` into the directory `two`.

If directory `two` doesn't exist, then `mv one two` may be interpreted as move the **file** `one` to the **file** `two` (a rename). Of course, if file `two` already exists, the user may be prompted if he wants to overwrite it (or other options).

It seems that when the option `--strip-trailing-slash` is used, the meaning is lock into move `one` **file** into a **directory** (not a rename).

If you still want to rename a directory while using `--strip-trailing-slash`, you must declare that there is no directory:

```
mv -T one two
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir one
$ ln -s one two
$ mv two/ yes
mv: cannot move 'two/' to 'yes': Not a directory

$ mv --strip-trailing-slash two/ yes
mv: cannot move 'two' to 'yes': Not a directory

$ mv -T --strip-trailing-slash two/ yes

$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 isaac isaac 4096 Jul 01 03:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 isaac isaac 4096 Jul 01 03:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 isaac isaac 4096 Jul 01 03:38 one
lrwxrwxrwx 1 isaac isaac    3 Jul 01 03:38 yes -> one
```